# Format an integer as both hex and decimal

Tags: c++, string, formatting, fmt

I want to add a format specifier to fmt that modifies how integers are formatted. Specifically I need printing an integer as both hex and decimal, e.g. in the form "0xff (256)".

It seems that I can only add custom formatters for custom types though.
So for example, something like this wont work:

```
using myint = uint64_t;
template <> struct fmt::formatter<myint> {
  constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context& ctx) -> decltype(ctx.begin()) {
    auto it = ctx.begin(), end = ctx.end();
    if(it != end && *it == 'z')
        it++;
    return it;
  }

  template <typename FormatContext>
  auto format(const myint& p, FormatContext& ctx) const -> decltype(ctx.out()) {
      return fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "z: {:x} {}", p, p);
  }
};
```

Even when i limit myself to a specific type of integer.
Are there any other ways?

Comment: Is using a strong-type library like [strong_type](https://github.com/rollbear/strong_type) an option for you?

Comment: The C++ <format> library did born kind of useless ... no internationalisation support, no positional specifiers, no UTF-8. IOW minimally useful toy library similar to <regex> and other sisters. Just use struct myint {uint64_t val;}; if you want to use it at all.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, type_safe would be probably even better suited, but i fear that would be overkill...

Comment: Öö Tiib, <format> has everything that you mentioned =)

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to wrap an integer in your type and provide a `formatter` specialization for that, for example:

```
#include <fmt/core.h>

struct myint {
  uint64_t value;
};

template <> struct fmt::formatter<myint> {
  constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context& ctx) {
    return ctx.begin();
  }

  auto format(myint n, format_context& ctx) const {
    return fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "z: {0:x} {0}", n.value);
  }
};

int main() {
  fmt::print("{}\n", myint{42});
}
```

This prints:

```
z: 2a 42
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rj9Eq6oax